# Slicer based on a condition(filter)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have 4 tables called survey data, survey data2 (for drill through of survey data), question mapping, dependencyQuestions

The schema for each is as follows:

-Survey data/survey data2: responseId, questionID, response
question mapping: questionId, questionText

-dependencyQuestions: mainquestion, dependent questions

The model is as follows :

[image]

I want to create a comparison page where in if i select the main question in LHS slicer, only the dependent questions should appear in the RHS slicer :

[image]

Right now i m using the survey data 2 for rhs slicer, but its already in many to many relation with survey data because of drill through requirement.

any work around to solve this.

I have made a calculated table for the dependent question as well

```
Dependent Question List = 
VAR Main_Question = SELECTEDVALUE(SurveyData[Mainquestion])
VAR depe = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        VALUES(Depende[Dependent Question]), 
        FILTER(ALL(Depende), Depende[Main Question] = Main_Question)
    )
RETURN 
    CONCATENATEX(depe, Depende[Dependent Question], ", ")
```